# didSelectRowAtIndex for two different cells - watchKit

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, watchkit, apple-watch

I have a tableView in my watchKit.
My goal is to use a different function depending on which cell was pressed (i have two buttons placed in two different cells).

That's the code i've been executing before

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    if table==tableView && rowIndex==tableView.numberOfRows-2 {
        print("Its up")
        print(tableView.numberOfRows)
    } else if table==tableView && rowIndex==tableView.numberOfRows-1 {
        print("It's down")
        print(tableView.numberOfRows)
    } else {
        print("Nothing is happening")
    }
}
```

the issue is - it doesn't always work, sometimes it just freezes the app.

Maybe you can advise any other solutions to this seemingly simple issue?

Thank you

Comment: Are you showing fixes number of cells in your tableView?

Comment: And what does your method1 and 2 do?

Comment: can you show ur cellforroratindexpath

Comment: @BharatModi yes and no - the table appends, but the two cells with buttons always have the same indexRow.

Comment: @BharatModi perform the simple function print("method performs")

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik this is watchKit, there is no cellForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

```
 override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
     if table==tableView && rowIndex == 0 {
         print("Its up")
         print(tableView.numberOfRows)
     } else if table==tableView && rowIndex == 1 {
         print("It's down")
         print(tableView.numberOfRows)
     } else {
         print("Nothing is happening")
  }
```

}

hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you are suggesting using rowIndex as 0 and 1 - they are not fixed and change according to the numberOfrows in the tableView